# How do I Listen for change in the text of an object using MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

Let's say I have a span such as this

```
<span id="theSpan"></span>
```

Using WebKitMutationObserver (I'm developing an extension for chrome, so no worries about cross-browser issues), how do i listen for changes within the span (innerText)? ie. the event should fire when i do this:

Javascript

```
$("#theSpan").text('hello world');
```

HTML

```
<span id="theSpan">Hello World</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to create `WebKitMutationObserver` instance, and then simply attach it to your `<span>` using `observe` method. The code will look like this:

```
// find element and create an observer instance
var target = $('#theSpan');
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    $('#log').text('input text changed: "' + target.text() + '"');
});
observer.observe(target[0], { childList: true});
//observer.disconnect(); - call this to stop observing

// test case
setInterval(function(){
    target.text('hello world ' + Math.random() + '!!!');
},1000);
​
```

Don't forget to pass real DOM object to observer, not jQuery object. Working fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hZKP2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#in1');
var display = document.querySelector('#dsp');
var MO = MutationObserver || WebKitMutationObserver || MozMutationObserver; 
var observer = new MO(function(mutations) {
  var _this = this;
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    dsp.innerHTML = _this._root.innerText || _this._root.textContent;
  });    
});

var config = {  //attributes: true, 
        //childList: true, 
                characterData: true, 
                subtree: true 
                };
 
observer.observe(target, config);
observer._root = target;

setInterval(function(){},250);
```

```css
div{
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 0.75rem 0;
  padding: 0.1rem 0.25rem 0.1rem 0.25rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: gray;
}

.input{
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  min-height: 1.25rem;
}
.display{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="in1" class="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="dsp" class="display"></div>
```

I think the code is a self-explanatory. Maybe one thing to note - the empty SetInterval. This is because of MAC OS Safari in which, I do not know why, MutationObserver do not work as expected w/o SetInterval. You can play with the interval value, lower value means more responsive MO. In other browsers (Chrome and Firefox - on MAC OS) it works well even w/o SetInterval.