# How to run script when page loads content dynamically for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have a script than runs at page finished loading to insert some stuff to the DOM. 
How to listen for when page is loading more content dynamically? One example of this dynamic loading is when you scroll down your feed on facebook, and more content is added to the list as you scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MutationObserver` to do this. Check documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Example of usage and fiddle available in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498921/how-do-i-listen-for-change-in-the-text-of-an-object-using-mutationobserver/13499973#13499973).