# Jquery - check if control is NOT currently being edited

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that updates controls on my page using Javascript/Ajax/Json calls.

My only problem is that sometimes the control is updated while the user is actively attempting to change the control.

For example - I will be typing in something, and the Ajax call will execute, replacing what I have typed.

Is this a way in javascript/jquery to say:

If $(this).NotBeingCurrentlyEdited ?

I know about the focus option, but how can I say "Not in focus, not being edited currently?"

Comment: Do you mean that multiple users shouldn't be able to edit the values simultaneously?

Comment: On focus, you could add a data attribute called, `data-mode="active"` or something like that. This way you can grab all the fields that do not have this "active" state e.g. `$('input[data-mode!="active"]')` You can check the current input via `$(this).data('mode') !== 'active'`

Comment: [How do I Listen for change in the text of an object using MutationObserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498921/how-do-i-listen-for-change-in-the-text-of-an-object-using-mutationobserver)

Comment: There is no built-in way of doing that, no, because there is no universal method for determining when a user is "currently editing" a field. For instance, a user could set the focus to a field, then go get a beverage. Are they "editing" that field?

Comment: You could flag the textbox as being edited using Javascript's oninput.  Then start a timer to reset whatever you use as a flag.

Comment: simply have the ajax code not update an element that is currently focused. easy.

Comment: there's a .not()-function from jquery you could use. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.activeElement` to check which element has the focus. If the element you want to change has the focus then skip the update. See example snippet below.

```js
var val = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  $('input').each((i, el) => {
    if (document.activeElement !== el) {
      $(el).val(val);
    }
  });
  val++;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="1">
<input id="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach it is using a timer to determine if the textbox has recently been changed by the user.  You could combine this with checking the control's focus as well once an Ajax request is received.  You can either disregard updates to that field entirely when TextBoxIsBeingEdited = true or store the updates somewhere to push once the timer ticks.

```js
var TextBoxIsBeingEdited = false;

function TextBoxEdited(){
  if(TextBoxIsBeingEdited === false){
    document.getElementById("TextBoxStatus").innerText = "Editing";
    TextBoxIsBeingEdited = true;
    setTimeout(ResetTextBoxEdited, 2000);
  } 
}

function ResetTextBoxEdited(){
  document.getElementById("TextBoxStatus").innerText = "Not Being Edited";
  TextBoxIsBeingEdited = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="TextBox" oninput="TextBoxEdited()">
<br><br>
<div id="TextBoxStatus">
  Not Being Edited
</div>
```